# How to get the size (in bytes) of output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

firstly, I would like to thanks to whomever would help me.

***- Environment***

I am using Python v2.7 in Windows 8 OS.
I am using COM4 to talk to robot by sending some commands in Python code.

I send a command `getversion` to robot and suppose to get a bunch of data which is in the following format (I omit some, it is too long):

> Component,Major,Minor,Build,Aux
>
> APPassword,956FC721
>
> BaseID,1.2,1.0,18000,2000,
>
> BatteryType,4,LIION_4CELL_SMART,
>
> Beehive URL, beehive.cloud.com
>
> BlowerType,1,BLOWER_ORIG,
>
> Bootloader Version,27828,,
>
> BrushMotorType,1,BRUSH_MOTOR_ORIG,
>
> BrushSpeed,1400,,
>
> BrushSpeedEco,800,,
>
> ChassisRev,1,,
>
> Cloud Selector, 2
>
> DropSensorType,1,DROP_SENSOR_ORIG,
>
> LCD Panel,137,240,124,
>
> LDS CPU,F2802x/c001,,
>
> LDS Serial,KSH13315AA-0000153,,

- My Question Is:
  Based on this format, how to get the size (in byte) of the above result? 
  The reason for this question is, I can get the full/complete result as long as I know how large it is.

To be specific, my code is:

```
ser.write('getver \n')   # send 'getversion' cmd to robot

ser.read(1305)
```

The response size of `getver` is 1305 byte, yes, I count it manually, that is why I would like to ask Python to tell me how large it is automatically.

Comment: Probably something like: `data=ser.read()` then `size=len(data)`

Comment: It does not look like the answer will always have the same size. There has to be a different way to read the response. Maybe you shoud set up a reasonable timeout (to detect the end) and then call `ser.readlines()`?

Comment: Can you program the robot? e.g. make it output something like "END" at the end of its output.

Comment: Also, as zvone mentioned, your output will be of different lengths possibly. However, the number of lines should be the same. Why not keep reading until you have 16 newlines?

Comment: you are right, the output will be different with dif size and lines. So I am afraid I cannot keep tracking 16 newlines bc they are dif... =(

Comment: Hi Iron Fist, thanks for the reply. I tried len(data), but it is the cmd to read length, what we need is to get size. So I tried sys.getsizeof(data), but it does not work...

Comment: Hi @zvone, yes, the answer will not have same size, I tried readline(), however, it does not work. I am thinking setup a timeout...um...but how to define "the end" if the output is line by line...

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to communicate with a device, you have to know what the protocol is for that communication. Whoever designed the protocol had to define a way for you to know how many bytes to read. If you have a specification, it probably covers that question.

So, there is either a way to determine number of bytes beforehand or to detect the end of transmission, e.g. by the existance of a special end character.

Without some sort of specification, we can only guess what the protocol is.

- The response message size is apparently not fixed. Maybe there is a way to ask the device "what would be the length of the answer to *getversion*"?
- Some protocols would prefix each message with the length information. Here there is none. Perhaps you can put the device in a different mode where it deos something like that by sending it some special command?
- Your message does not look like it has as the end marked, but perhaps it is just not visible, e.g. might there be a null character (`'\0'`) at the end? If there is one, you could read character-by-character until it appears.
- Failing to find any other solution, you can try setting a reasonable timeout on reads (`ser = serial.Serial(..., timeout=2, ...)`). Then try to read everything. When there is nothing more to read, the `read` function will freeze indefinitely, unless there is a timeout. If you set a reasonably long timeout and no date is received in that time, you can assume the transmission is over.