# Split and extract specific items from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am newie in this area, any help would be appreciated in advance.

I am using Python v2.7 in Windows 8 OS.
Now I have a list:

```
data = ['testmode on  \r', 'getdigitalsensors \r', '\x1aDigital Sensor Name, Value\r', 
'SNSR_DC_JACK_IS_IN,0\r', 'SNSR_DUSTBIN_IS_IN,1\r', 'SNSR_LEFT_WHEEL_EXTENDED,0\r', 
'SNSR_RIGHT_WHEEL_EXTENDED,0\r', **'LSIDEBIT,0\r', 'LFRONTBIT,0\r'**,
'LLDSBIT,0\r', **'RSIDEBIT,0\r', 'RFRONTBIT,0\r'**, 'RLDSBIT,0']
```

Question:

1. How to split/extract these 4 items (in bold) from the list ['LSIDEBIT,0\r', 'LFRONTBIT,0\r','RSIDEBIT,0\r', 'RFRONTBIT,0\r']?
2. How to split/extract the bit (0) after the above four items? The output is like:

   ```
   0
   0
   0
   0
   ```

Comment: For question 1., will the items you need to extract be given to you in a list (as in your example)?

Comment: well...that is a good question, not necessary a list. Second question is the key~ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
selected = [data[index] for index in [7, 8, 10, 11]]
res = [int(x.strip().split(',')[-1]) for x in selected]
```

If you don't know the indices before hand but the first part of the strings, you could do something like this:

```
targets = ['LSIDEBIT', 'LFRONTBIT','RSIDEBIT', 'RFRONTBIT']
selected = []
for item in data:
    for target in targets:
        if item.startswith(target):
            selected.append(item)
res = [int(x.strip().split(',')[-1]) for x in selected]
```

and `res` holds:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the prompt reply. The way you provide is an good and easy way. Sorry I did not make it clear, the list might be changed (some new items might be added), so I am afraid I cannot track them down by index 7,8,10,11.

Comment: Added a second version. Does it cover the cases you have in mind?

Comment: The new version looks better. I add 'print item' at the end of your answer, um...did not see any output...I must make sth. wrong...

Comment: The result is the list. I store it in `res` now.

Comment: `res = [int(x.strip().split(',')[-1]) for x in selected]` See answer.

Comment: ...so..shame...how can I ask this stupid question....yes, I print 'res', and it works! And then I can parse them further by res.[0], res[1].... THANKS Mike, I will vote your answer. =)

Comment: BTW, I believe you are an Python expertise, can you kindly help me out on this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050043/how-to-get-the-size-in-bytes-of-output-in-python

Comment: @Amber.G You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression groups to extract the bit:

```
import re
toextract = ['LSIDEBIT', 'LFRONTBIT','RSIDEBIT', 'RFRONTBIT']
for exitm in toextract:
    for itm in data:
        if itm.startswith(exitm):
            bitre = re.search(exitm+r',(\d)', itm)
            if bitre is not None:
                print bitre.group(1)
                break
```

Comment: um...an error:  in <module>
    bitre = re.search(exitem+r',(\d)', itm)
NameError: name 'exitem' is not defined

Comment: Great, you give me the exact output I want, vote for you. Tons of thx! =)

Comment: Any chance you can help me figure this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050043/how-to-get-the-size-in-bytes-of-output-in-python/34059088#34059088

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
l = ['testmode on \r', 'getdigitalsensors \r', '\x1aDigital Sensor Name, Value\r', 'SNSR_DC_JACK_IS_IN,0\r', 'SNSR_DUSTBIN_IS_IN,1\r', 'SNSR_LEFT_WHEEL_EXTENDED,0\r', 'SNSR_RIGHT_WHEEL_EXTENDED,0\r', 'LSIDEBIT,0\r', 'LFRONTBIT,0\r', 'LLDSBIT,0\r', 'RSIDEBIT,0\r', 'RFRONTBIT,0\r', 'RLDSBIT,0']

for i in map(l.__getitem__,[7,8,10,11]):
        print [int(s) for s in i.split(',')[1] if s.isdigit()]
```

output:

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
```

Comment: Thx Letsc, that is a brilliant idea. However, I am afraid I cannot track those four items down by index because the list might be changed, (say, add or delete some items...) @letsc